# Comparing parts of two array values

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays:

```
sortKey: ["invoiceDate-desc", "invoiceDate-asc", "location-asc", "location-desc", "orderId-asc", "orderId-desc", "invoiceId-asc", "invoiceId-desc", "type-asc", "type-desc", "total-asc", "total-desc"]
```

and

```
receivedOrderKey: ["invoiceId", "orderId"]
```

I want to compare the above two arrays such that the result will contain all the values present in `sortKey` which matches partially with the values present in `receivedOrderKey`. For example: as `receivedOrderKey` contains `invoiceId` and  `orderId`, the result should contain the following values from sortKey : `"invoiceId-desc, "invoiceId-asc", "orderId-asc", "orderId-desc"`. I am presently using a two for loop solution to make this work. What would be an efficient way of doing this?

Code with for loops:

```
          for(i=0;i<sortKey.length;i++){
            var str1 = sortKey[i].toLowerCase();
            for(j=0;j<receivedOrderKey.length;j++){
                var str2 = receivedOrderKey[j].toLowerCase();

                if(str1.includes(str2))
                {
                    requestedOptions.push(sortKey[i]);

                }
            }
        }

requestedOptions: ["orderId-asc", "orderId-desc", "invoiceId-asc", "invoiceId-desc"]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: First write your "two for loops" solution.  With arrays this size, go for readable, maintainable code.  Unless this is running thousands of times a second, you shouldn't need to worry about efficiency.

Comment: This is part of another code which will have ajax trigger on clicking "Search". This will have to be done every time as part of the requirements. Is it still okay?

Comment: Your ajax call across the network to a server will be orders of magnitude slower.  Write readable code.

Comment: I've added the logic I'm using presently

Comment: @Nightshade Asking again, what is the expected output?

Comment: @gurvinder372 the expected output is shown in requestedOptions. It is whichever value in sortKey contains the value of any of the values in array receivedOrderKey

Comment: How do those values make sense?  Assuming that these will be used to sort something, you're first going to sort by order id in increasing order, then again by decreasing order?

Comment: It's actually user dependent. so they can choose how to sort the data .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter`

```
sortKey.filter( s => receivedOrderKey.indexOf( s.replace(/\-(asc|desc)/, "") ) != -1 );
```

**Demo**

```js
var sortKey = ["invoiceDate-desc", "invoiceDate-asc", "location-asc", "location-desc", "orderId-asc", "orderId-desc", "invoiceId-asc", "invoiceId-desc", "type-asc", "type-desc", "total-asc", "total-desc"];

var receivedOrderKey = ["invoiceId", "orderId", "status"];



var fnCheck = ( item ) => receivedOrderKey.indexOf( item.replace(/\-(asc|desc)/, "") ) != -1;

var output = sortKey.filter( s => fnCheck(s) );

console.log( output );
```